# Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring Boot for a project and I just implemented a find by ID mapping, but when I call it I get this response:

Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Index -1 out of bounds for length 0]

It happens with the findAll() method too, but the item with the id is in the database so I am extremely confused. I was thinking it might be an issue with my JPA relationships since its a relationship heavy table. Any clue on where to even start with figuring out the error?

Heres the mapping I'm calling:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}/players")
public Set<Player> getPlayers(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    GameState state = repo.findById(id).get();
    return state.getTurnOrder();
}
```